# How to check are there any records in recordset in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Could you help me, please. I have a database in Access and a program written in Delphi (I've used the library Ehlib), which I'm trying to rewrite in the VBA.

```
with CustomDriver do
  try
    with SelectCommand do
    begin
      CommandText.Text := 'select count(*) from OBJ_APP a' + ^M +
                          'where ID_App = :AID_App and exists (select 1 from obj_app b where b.ID_Obj = a.ID_Obj and b.ID_App = :AID_App_Replace)';
      Parameters.ParamByName('AID_App').Value := AID_App;
      Parameters.ParamByName('AID_App_Replace').Value := AID_App_Replace;
    end;
    vFree := True;
    ExecuteCommand(SelectCommand, DsReplace, vFree);
if (DsReplace <> Nil)
and(DsReplace.RecordCount > 0)
and(DsReplace.Fields[0].AsInteger > 0) then
```

How do I write the last three lines of code in VBA? And is there an easier way to write double quotes than `& Chr (34) &`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to check for `.EOF` after opening a recordset.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM foo")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    If rs(0) > 0 Then
    ' or if you want to be explicit
    If rs.Fields(0).Value > 0 Then
```

Double quotes are masked by doubling them:

```
Debug.Print "Hello ""World"""
```

But usually you can make your code better readable by using single quotes:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 'something'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check `RecordCount`:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From YourTable")
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    ' At least one record exists.
    ' Do stuff.
End If
```

Answer (score -3):

All answers are wrong.

Wrong, cause ...

**1. Before records counting the recordset must be populated!

2. It's strongly NOT recommended to directly use of `CurrentDb`**

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM foo"

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb .OpenRecordset(sSQL)

With rst
    Select Case (.BOF And .EOF)
        Case True
            lCnt = 0
        Case False
            .MoveLast: .MoveFirst
            lCnt = .RecordCount
    End Select
End With

Call rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing 

Call cdb.Close
Set cdb = Nothing
```

.

Comment: If you know what you do `CurrentDb().Method`is not dangerous, On this case it is used once, no need to store the refrence. You should not use it multiple times (e.g. loops), instead  use it in a `With`statement, that's safe /in your code you could use `With Currentdb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)`-> no object vars to take care)).. If you open a recordset without editing, use readonly.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher , there is conception of "The best practice". It says - do like it and do not hesitate on is it "dangerous" or not :) How much you want to save on denial of this `cdb` variable? You are the one-line coder? OK. Forward!.

Comment: In this case I save 108 chars (cdb + rst) (252 to 360) ;) Main motivation is to fight myths. Of course not to use it is recommended for beginners, but if you know better, use your knowledge.

Comment: It is this answer that is if not wrong then overly complicated. The question is if _any_ record is found, not how many, so no need to retrieve all records with MoveLast as this could take a considerable time. And using CurrentDb directly for a single call is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Gustav , the answers I call wrong proposes the wrong approach. And your statement of _"considerable time"_ not applied in conext of OP skill. Even, in this case, it's ease restrict the check by EOF & BOF only. But neccessary of recordset populating must to be keeped in mind.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, and we all have our preferences, but that doesn't make other methods wrong - perhaps more or less suited for different scenarios, but here all are valid.

Comment: @Gustav , right. However there is a little nuance - our preferences cease to be our property, as soon as we recommend them to an unlimited circle of persons. And from this moment we are responsible for those preferences that we recommended to someone.